# Merge tuple with multiple item python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, merge, concatenation

I need my script to merge tuples with multiple items. I have:

```
list = [('France', 'Euro', 'Paris'), ('France', 'Euro', 'Marseille'), 
('Allemagne', 'Euro', 'Berlin'),
('Allemagne', 'Euro', 'Hambourg'), ('Allemagne', 'Euro', 'Munich'),
('France', 'Euro', 'Lyon'), ('Turquie', 'Livre', 'Ankara')]
```

and I want:

```
list = [('France', 'Euro', 'Paris', 'Marseille', 'Lyon'), 
('Allemagne', 'Euro', 'Berlin', 'Hambourg', 'Munich'),
('Turquie', 'Livre', 'Ankara')]
```

I have found :

```
for t in j:
    d.setdefault(t[0], set()).add(t[1])
result = tuple(tuple([k]+list(v)) for k, v in d.items())
```

But I can only merge item if I have 2 item per line.

I have tried to modify the logic but have not succeeded.

Comment: Please *explain* just which tuples are to be merged, on what basis, and how. Your example is not clear.

Comment: is it always the first two items in the tuple that are the same, and the third that changes?

Comment: Please don't overwrite `list`.

Comment: the first two item in the tuple is always the same

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems with your code:

1. You are looking to group by Country and Currency. Yet your dictionary only uses Country keys.
2. Your tuple comprehension will only ever return a tuple, while you want a list of tuples as output.
3. You are shadowing the built-in `list` class, you should never do this.

You can instead use `collections.defaultdict` with tuple keys, followed by a list comprehension:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for ctry, ccy, city in L:
    d[(ctry, ccy)].append(city)

res = [k+tuple(v) for k, v in d.items()]

print(res)

[('France', 'Euro', 'Paris', 'Marseille', 'Lyon'),
 ('Allemagne', 'Euro', 'Berlin', 'Hambourg', 'Munich'),
 ('Turquie', 'Livre', 'Ankara')]
```

Comment: Why convert the tuple to list and back to tuple? `[k+tuple(v) for k, v in d.items()]`

Comment: @tobias_k, Thanks, that's a fair point, I forgot that you can add tuples (though, of course, inefficient).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you want to iterate through the list, and combine the *third* element (being the currency) of each tuple which contains the same *second* and *first* element

This is how I would proceed:

```
currencies = {}
for i in lists:
    if (i[0],i[1]) in currencies.keys():
        currencies[(i[0],i[1])] = currencies[(i[0],i[1])]|set([i[2]])
    else:
        currencies[(i[0],i[1])] = set([i[2]])
lists = []
for c in currencies:
    lists.append(list(c) + list(currencies[c]))
print(lists)
```

this will yield:
`[['France', 'Euro', 'Marseille', 'Lyon', 'Paris'], ['Allemagne', 'Euro', 'Berlin', 'Munich', 'Hambourg'], ['Turquie', 'Livre', 'Ankara']]`

Though the result is not a tuple in the list, it still sorts the data, hope this helps!